# How to run a PostgreSQL function

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, function, plpgsql, toad

I am struggling to execute a PostgreSQL function. I am trying to read the documentation on the side but still no use. I am using [Toad Extension for eclipse to develop/run the function](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-extension-for-eclipse/b/weblog/archive/2014/10/07/introducing-toad-extension-for-eclipse-community-edition-v2-1-0)

So far, this is what I have written

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbName.function_name()
    RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    x_cur CURSOR FOR select * from dbName.x;
    x_row RECORD;
BEGIN
    OPEN x_cur;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Cursor opened';
    LOOP
        FETCH x_cur INTO x_row;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE x_cur;
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

I executed the script and then ran select dbName.function_name(); in the sql worksheet and I don't see any output.

I remember writing functions on plsqldeveloper was so easy and interactive and i am struggling with PostgreSQL, could you guys help me getting a headstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any problem using pgAdmin.

The function return `VOID`, but the `RAISE NOTICE` show the message.

I simplify the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name()
    RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
DECLARE   
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'Cursor opened';
END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

And execute the function

```
SELECT function_name();
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, thanks. Seems like i will be switching between IDE's. Could you recommend a documentation which list PLSQL equivalent functions in PLPGSQL ? I am looking for things like record.count, etc

Comment: Not really, I just use google and usually link to a question here.

Comment: PLpgSQL documentation is pretty short (but complete), start there http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/plpgsql.html or short introduction to plpgsql http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL/pgSQL_%28en%29